# Migrating from Java/EE5 to EE7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, migration, java-ee-5, java-ee-7

I'm currently trying to migrate a large EE5 application to EE7, but I'm pretty unluckily in finding good documentation to do this step *WITHOUT* porting to EE6 first.

My question is: is there a document describing exactly what I want? Or is that task to "adventurous" to be done in a single step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is: is there a document describing exactly what I want?

It is unlikely that you will find such a document (IMO).  Why?  Because there would be little point in writing one ... since it is simple to read *both* EE5 -> EE6 and EE6 -> EE7 and mentally combine the steps.

> Or is that task to "adventurous" to be done in a single step?

I wouldn't have thought so.  Generally speaking Java releases are mostly backwards compatible ... by design.  Of course, you may want to change your system to do things "the new way".  That will entail more work, and more risk in the short term, but it *should* be give you a code-base in the long term.